# I can't compile a 32-bit application for Windows XP support

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, boost-filesystem

I am trying to compile an app that I want to run on Windows XP.

My code utilizes the Boost library.

I have downloaded the mingw32 toolchain, alongside the i686 version of Boost.

Compiles fine and runs, but when I try to run it on Windows XP, I get an error

> the procedure entry point gettickcount64 could not be located kernel32.dll

I have tried searching around, I can't seem to find the solution, or understand what I need to change.

Here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS ${BOOST_ROOT}/libs)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_RELEASE_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_NO_WARN_NEW_VERSIONS ON)
find_package(Boost 1.79.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS system filesystem)

if (Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    add_executable(DoJaject main.cpp)
    target_include_directories(DoJaject PUBLIC ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    target_link_libraries(DoJaject PRIVATE Boost::filesystem Boost::system)
endif ()

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES "${CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES} -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++")

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,-Bstatic,--whole-archive -lwinpthread -Wl,--no-whole-archive")
```

I use CLion as my editor if that is something that could help

Comment: Does your code use `GetTickCount64`? The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-gettickcount64) says it was added in Vista so you'll need to find an alternative. `GetTickCount` is a good substitute although it can wrap around if the system is up for more than 49.7 days.

Comment: I don't use it, as in, I haven't written it in the code. Maybe boost libraries do, so that's why?

Comment: You might want to compile boost with `-D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501` and see where it pops

Comment: Also, https://github.com/search?p=1&q=org%3Aboostorg+gettickcount64&type=Code

Comment: @Osyotr Where would one write the argument? In the "Build options" or "CMake options"?

Comment: I tried adding the line with `add_compile_definitions()` in CMakeLists.txt and also Build options but still the same issue

Comment: https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/5139

Comment: @Osyotr: `-D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501` might be a challenge with newer SDK's. Microsoft dropped support for XP years ago. And if the code uses a new Boost 1.79, then the old SDK might be insufficient.

Comment: @MSalters I am going to downgrade pthreads and do I also downgrade boost version?

Comment: @DavidPetriashvili: That might be necessary. But this project will be complicated, so don't start downgrading immediately. Start with what you have now, document clearly at each point what doesn't work, and the steps you try to resolve it. This will take a lot of work - XP support is not going to be cheap.

Comment: Understandable. Thank you.